# Templates for the Journal of Finance

Tags: templates, journal

and other known journals in finance and economics (jfe, rfs, aer, econometrica, jpe,...): links would be highly appreciated, by me and I guess by many users. If you know the links please post them! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you be a bit more specific about the types of "templates" you're hoping to be pointed too? Are you looking for LaTeX templates to typeset a working paper in a given journal's preprint style, or are you looking for BibTeX style files (templates), or possibly both?

Answer (score 2):

TeXLive features a number of bibliography style files suitable for journals in field of economics. On my system (MacTeX2019), the following styles are available under `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/economic`: `aer`, `agecon`, `cje`, `ecca` (Economica), `ecta` (Econometrica), `ier`, `jae`, and `jpe`, and a few others more

Ivo Welch, a professor of finance at the Anderson School of Business at UCLA (as well as an occasional contributor to TeX.SE and the comp.text.tex newsgroup), used to maintain an extensive list of BibTeX bibliography style (`.bst`) on his website. As of July 2019, [his website](http://www.ivo-welch.info/professional/rfs-styles/) provides links to LaTeX style and bibliography style files suitable for the *Review of Financial Studies*, one of the "top three" finance journals.

Of course, BibTeX bibliography style files for econ-related journals published by Elsevier (e.g., the Journal of Financial Economics), Cambridge University Press (e.g., Econometric Theory), Chicago University Press, Oxford University Press (e.g., RFS), and other major publishing houses are also available for downloading from the respective publishers' websites. The RFS's own website, for instance, notes that

> ***References*** should be typed entirely double-spaced and begin on a separate page. They should be in alphabetical order, unnumbered, and follow the current edition of *The Chicago Manual of Style*. [bold-face and italics in the original]

If you wish to submit a paper to the RFS, you'll need need to make sure to include the instruction `\bibliographystyle{rfs}` in your paper (with `rfs.bst` to be downloaded from Ivo Welch's website). Alternatively, if you use `biblatex`, be sure to load the `biblatex-chicago` package.

Comment: @Miko I must be missing something but the OP is asking for LaTeX templates. You are taking about BibTeX database of various economics related journals. What is meaning of remark for TeX user? If there is a LaTeX template (which might very well not exist for the Journal in question as the final product is probably XML markup and most papers if not all are submitted in Word) then the template will take care of everything (double spaces for comments of referees, bibliography style, etc.). He should probably just go to the Journal's website and check directions for paper submission.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac: Actually, the OP does *not* state that he/she is looking for "LaTeX templates", but only for "templates", for  various econ journals. With the exception of the Elsevier-group journals, I know of no templates to make an econ working paper look like it's a preprint of a journal article. That's why I assumed that the OP is looking for *BibTeX* style files. Hopefully, though, the OP will choose to a be bit more specific with regard to what he/she is actually looking for. Finally, what makes you conjecture that "most [econ] papers if not all are submitted in Word"? Just curious.

Comment: I am just a guessing based upon economists from my circle of friends. I wish I was wrong and that there are more economists of the Timothy Van Zandt type. I know that you are one of them...

Comment: Welch's site let me speechless. :) RFS bibstyle can be found here http://www.ivo-welch.info/professional/index.html . However, JF bibstyle is missing (broken link).

Comment: The link in the answer is now broken.

Comment: Hi, dearest friend. Can you edit your answer, please? There is a link "not found". Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano - I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

Latex templates are here if that is what you are looking for

http://sourceforge.net/projects/economtex/

Answer (score 1):

full replication in biblatex is here: 
[biblatex: how to match the Journal of Finance bibliographic style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379901/biblatex-how-to-match-the-journal-of-finance-bibliographic-style)