# How can I make a Bibliography with Econometrica style?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, miktex, biber

Beginner here. I am learning how to make bibliographies and for my field of study I should cite in Econometrica style or similar, but I have no idea how.
Here's how I've been doing it so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa6]{biblatex} % or \usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{bb} 
\begin{document}
Primera i única cita \footcite{primer}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How can I elaborate a Bibliography in Economentrica (or similar, used in the field of economics/econometrics) Style? If so, how would you implement it in my code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you checked with the journal’s website if they offer a software solution to creating bibliographies and citation callouts in their preferred style? Please advise.

Comment: Would be helpful, if you gave an example of the desired format. And have you already checked the available styles on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/topic/biblatex)? Maybe there is one that fits your needs. It's always a good idea to check `biblatex-ext` which makes modifications of the standard styles easier.

Comment: Please also clarify what you mean by “Econometrica or similar”. I’m an econometrician, and in my opinion none of the other scholarly journals with an econometrics focus employ a bib style that comes close to Econometrica’s own, quite distinctive bib style.

Comment: By Econometrica or similar I mean the style of economic journals, for instance the American Economic Review or the Canadian Journal of Economics. On CTAN I found the "economic" package, but it works for bibtex, and I do not know how to implement it with biblatex. And I haven't found anything useful in that aspect yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only official guidance on the bibliography and citation style of *Econometrica* that are found are the the short paragraph and few examples in https://www.econometricsociety.org/publications/econometrica/information-authors/instructions-preparing-articles-publication. It is hard to build a full style from that (and I also believe that building a full style is a bit too big an ask for one TeX.SX question: ideally questions should be about specific issues that are of general interest so that they can be recycled for other styles and applications as well).

The following could be a basis for further customisations. I didn't go through the examples with a fine-tooth comb, so I expect to have missed some details.

*Econometrica* style is an author-year-type style. For easier customisability I picked a style from the `biblatex-ext` bundle, so the base style is `ext-authoryear` (you could also try `ext-authoryear-comp` if you like compressed citations).

The other modifications should be reasonably understandable if you look up the respective commands in the `biblatex` and `biblatex-ext` documentations or [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864). (But I'm happy to answer questions about specific pieces of code used in the MWE as well.)

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear,
  giveninits,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{textcite}{\textcite}{\textcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=textcite}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}

\autocite{nussbaum,cicero,westfahl:space}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E. and U. Ryde (1998): Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments, in: Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19.4, 377–395, doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Related [biblatex: how to match the Journal of Finance bibliographic style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/379901/35864).

Note that you probably can not use `biblatex` for journal submissions, see [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). If journals accept LaTeX they usually have some sort of submission guidance, a template or even a document class. If this is for journal submission, double check (with the editor if the information is not available by other means) that they can accept `biblatex`.